# How do I upgrade ChromeDriver on a C# Selenium project?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a C#-based Selenium test successfully running in a Github Actions container. It worked until recently, where presumably Github upgraded the ChromeDriver version of the `ubuntu-latest` image to `87`.

After this(started failing on Dec. 2nd), I got the following:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.87 (<uuid>-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#1689}) on port 35539
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
  X SomeTestThatShouldpass [5s 387ms]
  Error Message:
   System.InvalidOperationException : session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85 (SessionNotCreated)
```

Following this, I upgraded the ChromeDriver dependency in my `*.csproj`:

Before:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="85.0.4183.8700" />
```

After:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="87.0.4280.8800" />
```

However, after bumping the version I'm left with the very same error as above. It still starts ChromeDriver 85, and still brings forth an error in relation to version mismatches.

Apparently, bumping the dependency and building the .NET application again did not upgrade the ChromeDriver version.

How do I upgrade the ChromeDriver version from 85 to 87?

Comment: Delete the previous ChromeDriver from your files, then install again from here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: It runs in a Github Actions container. It's already there in version `87.0.4280.20`. https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-README.md

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ChromeDriverPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        string ChromDriverVersion = GetChromDriverVersion(ChromeDriverPath);
        string ChromeWebVersion = GetWebChromeVersion();

        if (ChromDriverVersion != ChromeWebVersion)
        {
            var urlToDownload = GetURLToDownload(ChromeWebVersion);
            KillAllChromeDriverProcesses();
            DownloadNewVersionOfChrome(urlToDownload, ChromeDriverPath);
            string extract = ExtructZip(ChromeDriverPath);
        }
    }

    static string GetChromDriverVersion(string ChromeDriverePath)
    {
        string driverversion = "";
        if (File.Exists(ChromeDriverePath + "\\chromedriver.exe"))
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverePath);
            ICapabilities capabilities = ((ChromeDriver)driver).Capabilities;
             driverversion = ((capabilities.GetCapability("chrome") as Dictionary<string, object>)["chromedriverVersion"]).ToString().Split(' ').First();
            driver.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ChromeDriver.exe missing !!");
        }


        return driverversion;
    }
    static string GetChromeWebPath()
    {
        //Path originates from here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection            
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\chrome.exe"))
        {
            if (key != null)
            {
                Object o = key.GetValue("");
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(o.ToString()))
                {
                    return o.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Unable to get version because chrome registry value was null");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Unable to get version because chrome registry path was null");
            }
        }
    }
    static string GetWebChromeVersion()
    {
        string productVersionPath = GetChromeWebPath();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(productVersionPath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Unable to get version because path is empty");
        }

        if (!File.Exists(productVersionPath))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to get version because path specifies a file that does not exists");
        }

        var versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(productVersionPath);
        if (versionInfo != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(versionInfo.FileVersion))
        {
            return versionInfo.FileVersion;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Unable to get version from path because the version is either null or empty: " + productVersionPath);
        }
    }
    static string GetURLToDownload(string version)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(version))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Unable to get url because version is empty");
        }

        //URL's originates from here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection
        string html = string.Empty;
        string urlToPathLocation = @"https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_" + String.Join(".", version.Split('.').Take(3));

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlToPathLocation);
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            html = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(html))
        {
            throw new WebException("Unable to get version path from website");
        }

        return "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/" + html + "/chromedriver_win32.zip";
    }
    static void KillAllChromeDriverProcesses()
    {
        var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("chromedriver");
        foreach (var process in processes)
        {
            try
            {
                process.Kill();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
    static void DownloadNewVersionOfChrome(string urlToDownload,string ChromDriverPath)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(urlToDownload))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Unable to get url because urlToDownload is empty");
        }
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            if (File.Exists(ChromDriverPath + "\\chromedriver.zip"))
            {
                File.Delete(ChromDriverPath + "\\chromedriver.zip");
            }

            client.DownloadFile(urlToDownload, "chromedriver.zip");

            if (File.Exists(ChromDriverPath + "\\chromedriver.zip") && File.Exists(ChromDriverPath + "\\chromedriver.exe"))
            {
                File.Delete(ChromDriverPath + "\\chromedriver.exe");
            }

        }
    }
    static string ExtructZip(string ChromeDriverPath)
    {
        string errorMsg = "";
        string zipFileName = "";
        try
        {
            zipFileName= System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "\\chromedriver.zip";
            string orgFileName = "";
            using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipFileName))
            {
                foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
                {
                    e.Extract(ChromeDriverPath, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
                    orgFileName = e.FileName;
                }
            }
            File.Delete(zipFileName);
            errorMsg = "Done";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorMsg = "ExtructZip  file " + zipFileName.Split('\\').Last() + " - " + ex.Message;
        }
        return errorMsg;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rosolko/WebDriverManager.Net

Use WebDriver manager to automatically install the version , you want

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using WebDriverManager;
using WebDriverManager.DriverConfigs.Impl;

namespace Test
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests
    {
        private IWebDriver _webDriver;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig(), "2.25");
            _webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            _webDriver.Quit();
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            _webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
            Assert.True(_webDriver.Title.Contains("Google"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please comment something if you have better solution

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace UpdateChromeDriver
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Specify the path where the ChromeDriver executable is located
            string driverPath = "path_to_chromedriver_directory";
            // Specify the URL to download the latest ChromeDriver executable
            string downloadUrl = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE";

            try
            {
                // Download the latest ChromeDriver version number
                string latestVersion = new WebClient().DownloadString(downloadUrl).Trim();

                // Create the download URL for the specific operating system and architecture
                string downloadLink = $"https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/{latestVersion}/chromedriver_win2.zip";

                // Download the zip file
                using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    webClient.DownloadFile(downloadLink, "chromedriver.zip");
                }

                // Extract the zip file
                System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("chromedriver.zip", driverPath);

                // Delete the downloaded zip file
                File.Delete("chromedriver.zip");

                Console.WriteLine($"ChromeDriver updated to version {latestVersion} successfully.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error updating ChromeDriver: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).